# REGEXP to extract a number from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for a bit of help regarding REGEXP. I have a varcher2 column with '7251.1 m' in the data set & I need to convert it to a number 7251.10

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select to_number(regexp_substr(col, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*'))
```

By default, Oracle doesn't print out the two decimal places.  You can convert back to a string if you need a particular format.

Comment: You're a legend & so quick... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would use the canonical regex pattern of `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`.  In the case of Oracle regex, there is no formal word boundary, but we can simulate it nonetheless:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '(^|\s)\d+(\.\d+)?(\s|$)'))
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo